# Why does my subscription's "Share Your Information" alert display the publisher name instead of app name?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We're putting together a newsstand app and have added a free subscription in-app purchase. The confirm subscription alert shows up corrently with the name of the app. However, the "Share Your Information" alert says the following...

The publisher of [OUR COMPANY NAME] would like your name, email...

At first I thought this was just terrible grammar, but I have seen this in other apps and it should display the app name, not the publisher name. I have tried running this in both debug and adhoc but I get the same result.

Would it be due to the fact that the subscription is still in a "Ready to Submit" state and it will get fixed in a distribution build? I would prefer not to submit the app until this has been resolved.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've got the same problem here!

Answer (score 7):

It seems that this occurs only when using sandbox mode of the App Store. When published using a production build, it corrects itself. All that stress for nothing! I'm surprised this bug slipped through Apple's net.

Answer (score 2):

This dialog always appears - even now in 2015 - while you are in Sandbox mode... i.e. either via a Sandbox IAP tester account or when testing via TestFlight.

There is a manual switch that the app review team must flip once the app is in review to disable the dialog. If you still see it after the app is on the store, then you need to mail the app review team.

I know this from my own experience with a productivity app which has auto-renewable subscriptions. I summed this experience up in [this talk](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2015/07/monetizing-your-apps-with-subscriptions/) I gave earlier this year; you can watch it on YouTube.